# Is there any JSON filter to restrict undefined properties that are passed in HTTP request in Spring REST API

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

```
{
  "id":100,
  "name":"Ram",
  "flag" : FALSE,
  "dept" :"Software"
}
```

Above is my JSON input format for one of my Spring 4.x REST API. Following is my DTO.

```
public class EmployeeDTO {

private long id;
private String name;
private Boolean flag;
private String dept;

//getXXX & setXXX
```

}

If I am passing any extra parameters like below, additional parameters are ignored by the application (by default, please correct if my assumption is wrong).

```
 {
  "id":100,
  "name":"Ram",
  "flag" : FALSE,
  "dept" :"Software"
  "extra1":"unwanted",
  "extra2" :"This also unwanted"
}
```

But, I do not want any extra fields to be in the input format, rather I want to restrict only DTO variables to be included in the input JSON. Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to reject the request containing any extra field?

Comment: Your title is confusing because `undefined` is an equivalent of `null` in Javascript. Therefore an _undefined property_ can be interpretted as a _null property_, whereas you mean to say _unexpected property_.

Comment: Did you try it? The unknown properties should throw a "Unrecognized property" exception as long as you didn't mark it `ignoreUnknownProperties`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to reject the request containing any extra field?  -> YES, I want to reject & throw an exception.